# QLDB high latency of ~5000ms

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, blockchain, latency, amazon-qldb

I am using the "aws-sdk:^2.576.0" and "amazon-qldb-driver-nodejs:0.1.0-preview.2", and following the [node-sdk's sample code for qldb](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-qldb-dmv-sample-nodejs).
I am calling the node-sdk functions via the REST APIs exposed.

So for the read table operation, i.e., `SELECT *` query ([`scanTable` from the sample code](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-qldb-dmv-sample-nodejs/blob/master/src/ScanTable.ts)), following is the latency breakdown:

[image]

I'm getting a new session for every transaction from the session pool using [`pooledQldbDriver.getSession()`](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-qldb-dmv-sample-nodejs/blob/master/src/ConnectToLedger.ts#L57) and have a decent internet connection of nearly 100mbps.

Is this much latency expected? Am I doing something wrong, and how can it be reduced further?

Comment: Hi Prashant. How are you measuring latency? Is this client side? And, what region are you running in and what is your latency to that region?

The short answer is "no". But I will need more information to help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: Hi Marc, I'm running on the region us-west-2 from India. I'm measuring the latency at client-side using `console.time()`. I haven't done complete benchmarking yet, but this is what I'm getting for now. Will changing the region or the sdk from node to java affect the current latency? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, significantly. Right now what you're measuring is the latency between your browser and us-west-2, not the latency of QLDB. You should select the endpoint with the lowest latency from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/qldb.html.

Comment: Or preferably start an EC2 instance or Lambda in the same region and run the test there. It cuts the round trip through your ISP and wifi out of the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(As per the comments in your question.)

Right now you're measuring the latency between India and us-west-2, not the latency of QLDB operations. Please use a region that has lower latency (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/qldb.html) or rely on the server-side metrics that you should be able to find in the CloudWatch console.